# Why intel xdk doesn't work in tablets with android 3.1?

Tags: html, intel-xdk, android-3.1-honeycomb

I'm making an app using intel xdk. It works in many devices but when i try in tablets with android 3.1 it doesn't work. The title of pannels is not displayed and the $.ui.ready is not fired. Even trying with this simple code it fails (the hello world button is not displayed either):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!--HTML5 doctype-->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var isIntel=window.intel&&window.intel.xdk
    // This event handler is fired once the intel libraries are ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //hide splash screen now that our app is ready to run
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ui.launch();
        }, 50);
    }
    //initial event handler to detect when intel is ready to roll
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
<script src="js/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if(isIntel)
        $.ui.autoLaunch = false;
    $.ui.useOSThemes = false; //Change this to false to force a device theme
    $.ui.blockPageScroll();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.ui.useOSThemes && (!$.os.ios||$.os.ios7))
            $("#afui").removeClass("ios");
    });

    $.ui.ready(function(){
        alert('uiready');
    //App is ready lets check if a user exists.


});
</script>
<link href="css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/af.ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="afui" class="ios">
    <div id="header" class="header"></div>
    <div id="content" style="">
        <div class="panel" title="Main" id="main" selected="selected"
        style="">
            <a class="button" href="#" style="" data-appbuilder-object="button">Hello World</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="footer">
        <a href="#main" class="icon home">Home</a>
    </div>




</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  What other devices does it work on?   Phones? PCs? and what other OS's?  Did you have the most recent version of the XDK installed?  The XDK supports Android 3.1 so either it's a bug in your code or a bug in the XDK.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it via usb? what is displaying the console?

Answer (score 0):

Check your text/html Content-Encoding in Header Data. With `Content-Encoding: gzip` this will not work. Maybe `.htaccess => Modul mod_filter.c`